# Express checkout button instead of pay with paypal button in iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, paypal

In my application, I am getting Pay with PayPal button but I want to get Express Check Out Button.
So, do I need any additional libraries for that? Or should I change my code ? I used sample Pizza library.
My button initialization code is

```
UIButton *button = [[PayPal getPayPalInst] getPayButtonWithTarget:self andAction:
                   @selector(payWithPayPal)andButtonType:BUTTON_118x24];
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
UIButton *button = [[PayPal getPayPalInst] getPayButtonWithTarget:self andAction:
                   @selector(payWithPayPal)andButtonType:BUTTON_118x24];
```

with

```
[[PayPal getInstance] fetchDeviceReferenceTokenWithAppID:yourAppId forEnvironment:ENV_LIVE withDelegate:self];
```

Take the custom `button` with any text as you want in IB or allocate new button at runtime & create instance of paypal as I created above in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: I don't have problem with the size of the button. I need label of the button "Check out with paypal". i seen this in website. so there is not a single way to get this in iphone application ?

Comment: I used same & it works fine, Also the app is live now. You may loosing something in code.

Comment: I am using SandBox and it is not working in it. But my question is how to get the check out with paypal button instead of pay with paypal button ? any idea ?

Comment: lets come on chat, I will tell you the detail process of paypal.

Comment: No... I think it's not possible in iPhone. if you have any idea then tell me please..

Comment: please come on chat on same room